# Problem installing gnome desktop - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dependencies

[image]

Its a fresh install of 14.04. I've done the obvious sudo apt-get update but stil not working. Im seriously new to ubuntu so please explain what you want me to do (Thanks alot in advance!)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/682482/edit) your question with the full error message ?

Comment: So sorry, my image didnt work. Edited.

Comment: it's a fresh install, have you performed an apt-get update and an apt-get upgrade?

Comment: @mchid i hadnt done upgrade, but i just have.. still nothing :(

Comment: Will you give a text output of these commands: `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  You might have to run them more than once to get all the needed updates and upgrades.   You can use the select and copy command and paste the content between <pre></pre> marks.  Using the preformatted markup will preserve the format that you see on your screen.

Comment: It's far too long to add in here, i'll stick it in a pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/xd6QuZYr
No matter how many times i do sudo apt-get update it keeps saying the same thing.

Comment: Im confused about this, you installed 14.04 with unity ? but want to install Gnome as your desktop ? Perhaps im missing something here but https://ubuntugnome.org/ Ubuntu with Gnome as default DE

Comment: You can install multiple desktops in Ubuntu.  You have the option of choosing which desktop and can also use per user desktop.  Also when performing remote desktop access you almost always need an alternative to Unity.  A good alternative is gnome.desktop.

Comment: The output answered a lot of my questions.  Will you do the same for `sudo apt-get install gnome.desktop`

Comment: I think you have to enable the universe and multiverse repositories in order to get a clean install of gnome-shell on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable the universe and multiverse repositories in order to get a clean install of gnome-shell on 14.04 because of all the dependencies. If you would like to add these repositories, run the following commands:

First, make a backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/backupsources
```

Then, edit the file:

```
sudo sed -i 's/main/main universe multiverse /g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Next, update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Now, you have two options. First, you could install using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install eog gnome-shell
```

Alternatively, it's much easier to install a default desktop on a system that does not yet have an xserver by using `tasksel` to automate the process somewhat.

First, install `tasksel`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Next, run tasksel, follow the on screen instructions, use the arrow keys to navigate, the spacebar to select or un-select, and the <kbd>enter</kbd> as normal. Do not select any "live" desktops.

```
sudo tasksel
```

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.